# Vector space determination for continuous functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let $f(x)$ be set of all real valued functions defined on set of real number such that

1)  $f(x)$  continuous on $[0,1]$

2)  $f(3/4)$=$0$

Does this set of functions constitute a vector space ?

The answer to this question is given to be No. 
According to me all the properties ( Internal, External composition , Abelian over addition and distribute property ) are satisfied by this set

Would appreciate if anyone could point out specific property which is not being satisfied in this case?

Comment: Do you mean to say "the set of functions $f \in C[0,1]$ such that $f(3/4)=0$ form a vector space"? Whay have you tried? Do you know the definition of a vector space, and did you tried to check whether all these properties are satisfied or not? Please share your thought and/or work?

Comment: I edited the question trying to make some sense of the last sentence, and happened to arrive at the same meaning @Krish is guessing at. If that is wrong please say what you mean, preferably by editing the question (and don't just roll my edit back, it also improves the formatting).

Comment: I want to specifically know which property is not being satisfied ? 
According to me Internal composition and external composition holds ,
the vector space also seems to be Abelian group over addition and satisfy the left distribution , right distribution properties too. ( Should I prove each one the of properties here?)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to ask , also along with f(3/4)=0 the condition states that f(x) is continuous on the [0,1] interval . Let me know if I can clarify any further

Comment: You just need to check if that set if functions will form a subspace of $C[0,1]$. So for closure under addition if we have $f$ and $g$ from that set, then $f+g$ is definitely continuous and will vanish at $x=3/4$. This means $f+g$ is in the set as well. Now you can check the remaining condition for subspace.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f,g \in C[0,1]$ such that $f(3/4)=g(3/4)=0$ and let $s \in \mathbb R$.

Furthermore put $h:=f+g$ and $k:=sf$.

Is $h \in C[0,1]$ ?

Is $k \in C[0,1]$ ?

Is $h(3/4)=0$ ?

Is $k(3/4)=0$ ?.

If we have "yes, yes,yes,yes " then the set in question is a vector space, otherwise not.

Comment: One minor(!) point: you have proved that the mentioned set is a vector subspace of $C[0,1]$. I'm not completely sure (based on OP's question and comments) whether this is obvious to OP. Probably it will be better to mention that $C[0,1]$ is a vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$)..